# Add an "ultimate threadgroup " in jmeter via java code

Tags: jmeter

I want to create and execute a JMeter JMX file using java code. The JMX file should contain an ultimate thread group. is it any way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
UltimateThreadGroup threadGroup = new UltimateThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setName("Ultimate Thread Group");
CollectionProperty ultimatethreadgroupdata = new CollectionProperty("ultimatethreadgroupdata", new ArrayList<>());
CollectionProperty schedule1 = new CollectionProperty("schedule1", new ArrayList<>());
Arrays.asList("100", "50", "20", "120", "40").forEach(schedule1::addItem);
ultimatethreadgroupdata.addProperty(schedule1);
threadGroup.setData(ultimatethreadgroupdata);
```

Just remember to:

1. Add [`kg.apc.jmeter-plugins-casutg` library along with dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-casutg/2.9) to your project classpath, otherwise it won't compile
2. Install [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle using [JMeter Plugins manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/), otherwise you will not be able to run the script.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Getting following error when i tried to execute the above code

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.initialize(AbstractThreadGroup.java:149) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:714) ~[ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.0.jar:5.0 r1840935]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]

Comment: ultimateThreadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController); resolves the null pointer. Now, the request is not executed, result.jlt is empty but its not throwin any error